# Import Excel file into SQL Server using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, import, import-from-excel

I have SQL Server 2012 and MS Office 2013. I am using Openrowset command:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;  
RECONFIGURE;
GO 
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;  
RECONFIGURE;  
GO  

EXEC sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'AllowInProcess', 1 
EXEC sp_MSset_oledb_prop N'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0', N'DynamicParameters', 1 

SELECT * INTO My_Table FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
                        'Excel 12.0;Database=D:\SQL\B0.xlsx',
                        'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
```

If I run as Administrator, the code runs fine. But if I use my user I get this error:

> OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)" returned message "Unspecified error".
>
> Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server "(null)".

My purpose is to import an Excel file with more than 300 000 rows. I use Import wizard, but it only works with about 65 000 rows, so I have to use T-SQL, but I get this error. Maybe my user does not have permissions to using code to import Excel by T-SQL. Do you have any way to solve this problem please help.

Comment: do you have `AccessDatabaseEngine` installed on server ?

Comment: Yes. AccessDatabaseEngine was installed

Comment: Are both 32 bit and 64 bit versions installed?

Comment: yes. I installed AccessDatabaseEngine_X64 and AccessDatabaseEngine from webside www.microsoft.com